# Laptop has 100% available plugged in charging and seems to be charging battery

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 5521  running Windows 8.1.Recently, I had replaced my battery. But my battery indicator shows 100% available ( plugged in,charging) status. I calibrated the battery but no difference. Battery is still in good condition and it still holds a 4-5 hours talk time.

What should I do to fix this problem or is it safe to continue using with AC power. Charging indicator bulb is turned on all the time so I feel that the laptop tries to overcharge the battery.

Will it reduce the battery life?

Comment: Li-Ion batteries will actually explode if over-charged. I'd make very sure it is not still charging when the battery is actually at 100%

Comment: Battery charging is controlled by the motherboard bios firmware not the power brick.

Comment: Was the new battery a Dell battery?

Comment: The battery has electronics in it that does not allow overcharge, overdischarge, overtemp and probably overcurrent. So it should not explode or anything.

Comment: @Moab the new battery was a dell battery

Comment: @Dan,[they don't always work](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1909&bih=1070&q=exploding+laptop+battery&oq=exploding+laptop+battery&gs_l=img.3..0i8i30j0i24.1255.1255.0.1773.1.1.0.0.0.0.56.56.1.1.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.1.55.zLTeQp0ttc4)

Comment: Any device will malfunction now and then (even the space rockets, see latest news). But _genuine_ (big emphasys on genuine) batteries exploding, that's rare (between other things, there usually is an actual thermal fuse in the battery pack)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to full discharge the battery (calibrate it) is to drain it as low as you can while in Windows, then restart the PC and enter the bios setup screen, leave it in setup until the battery drains and turns off the PC, then plug it in and let charge for a few hours before turning it on.

If no joy, try this. It may or may not remedy the issue:

- Disconnect AC
- Shutdown
- Remove battery
- Press and hold power button for 30 seconds
- Connect AC only (no battery)
- Startup
- Open Device Manager
- Click the plus (+) sign next to Batteries category, right-click all of the "Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery" listings, and select Uninstall In the "Confirm Device Uninstall" dialog box, click OK. (it’s ok if you only have 1 of these).
- Click the plus (+) sign next to System Devices.
- Right-click the “ACPI Fixed Features Button" and select Uninstall. In the "Confirm Device Uninstall" dialog box, click OK.
- Shutdown
- Disconnect AC
- Insert battery
- Connect AC
- Startup

Answer (score 0):

Dell has a (Laptop) charging system that is unique to other manufacturers. It incorporates a monitoring system based on technologies created by [1wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire).

It is *imperative* that you use a "Dell certified" charger (and battery). Or the system becomes unreliable, or broken. *Even* if the charger has the *same* "specs" -- power ratings. As such; if you, or a previous owner has used anything but that "Dell certified" charger. The charging system, and battery level indication will have been compromised. I am *not* saying this because I am a Dell employee, or affiliated in any way to Dell Inc. (I am not) in an effort to ensure you buy only Dell products. I say this because of research I performed before purchasing a new (Larger) battery for my own (Dell) Laptop.